# Equivalence of Hilbert spaces and application of dominated convergence theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{x_n\}$. Let $\{y_k\}$ a sequence of elements of $H$, show that the following statements are equivalents.
>
> (a) For all $x$ in $H,$ $(x,y_n)\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$
>
> (b) $(x_k,y_n)\to 0$ for each $k$ and $\{\|y_n\|\}$ is bounded.

Proof. Suppose (a). Since $\lim_n(x_k,y_n)= 0$ for each $k$, it's only necessary to check that $\{\|y_n\|\}$ is bounded.

Let $L_n(x)=(x,y_n)$ for all $n$. Clearly $L_n$ belongs to the dual of $H$. Since $\lim_n L_n(x)= 0$, we can find a $C(x)<\infty$ such that $\sup_n|L_n(x)|\le C(x)$ for any $x$. By the uniform boundedness principle $\sup_n\|L_n\|<\infty$, since $\|L_n\|=\|y_n\|$ we have that (a) implies (b).

Suppose (b). Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $H$, so $x$ can be expressed as $\sum_n c_n x_n$ where $c_n=(x,x_n)$, because $\{x_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis. Using the continuity of the inner product we have that $(x,y_k)=\sum_n c_n(x_n,y_k)$.

$$\|(x,y_k)\|_{\ell_ 2}\le \sup_n\|y_k\| \left(\sum_k |c_n|^2\right)^{1/2}=\sup_k\|y_k\| \|x\|<\infty.$$

From this I'll try to use dominated convergence theorem but unfortunately I can see how conclude that $(x,y_k)=\sum_n c_n(x_n,y_k)\to 0$ when $k\to \infty$. I'd appreciate your help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b)$\Rightarrow$(a), assume $\left\Vert y_{n}\right\Vert <M$.
For $\epsilon>0$, choose $x_{F}\in span\left\{ x_{k}\right\} $ s.t.
$\left\Vert x-x_{F}\right\Vert <\epsilon/M$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\left\langle x,y_{n}\right\rangle \right| & \leq & \left|\left\langle x-x_{F},y_{n}\right\rangle \right|+\left|\left\langle x_{F},y_{n}\right\rangle \right|\\
 & \leq & \epsilon+\left|\left\langle x_{F},y_{n}\right\rangle \right|\longrightarrow\epsilon,\;\mbox{as }n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{eqnarray*}